# How can I get call centre information from CallCenterAnywhere

Tags: services, api, database-administration

Our organisation uses some software called CallCenterAnywhere to manage a customer services centre which it does well as far as I can tell, but we'd like to extract some information from it to present on a nice interface, such as the number of calls in queue and the status of our services people.
After googling and reading numerous PDFs explaining that the software has a 'webservices API for 3rd party integration' I am yet to find a single shred of documentation on how to actually use these services, furthermore there seems to be no obvious endpoint for the services.

Does anyone have even the slightest idea of how I could get started?

Comment: I'm sure your organization has a support contract with Telus.  A good first step would be to contact Telus and ask them for the development/API documentation for CallCentreAnywhere.

Comment: +1 for @boot's comment. Asking them should be the first thing you try.

Comment: See if this helps http://www.doa.state.wi.us/sublink_print.asp?linksubcat2id=644&linksubcatid=&linkcatid=&locid=155

Comment: We have had a ticket logged with them for almost a year.

Comment: subanki - thanks for the link, it's a mixture of documentation I have and haven't seen, but ultimately there's nothing that helps with integrating applications.  It's mostly how to use the management software itself.

Comment: Since you tagged this as "oracle" im guessing there is a SQL back end.  You could probably check the schema/structure of that to get started, and create some queries to get the info you wanted.

Comment: @Baris: Good grief.  Still, Telus is providing the service, so they must have **some** kind of documentation.  You should pursue this with their support staff; specifically, you need to get your request bumped up the support chain until you get someone who can answer your question.  Just keep saying "Okay, you can't answer my question, so please connect me with someone who can."  If they still don't help, ask them for all their names, with correct spellings, for the TelusSupportSucks.com site you're building.  That might get their attention.